# Tkinter create_rectangle performance

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, rectangles

I'm using create_rectangle to draw and update a WxH grid on a canvas in an infinite loop. I notice the refresh rate greatly slows down after a few minutes. After doing some reading I realized that create_rectangle creates an object, which I think is causing my performance problem.
Is there a way to change the color of a rectangle object without creating a new rectangle?
If not, do I need to delete all the rectangles in the grid before redrawing the grid?
I think the performance issue is due to creating thousands of rectangles that never go away.

```
# Conway's Game of Life
# Algorithm and code taken from Al Sweigart's "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python"

import random, time, copy
from tkinter import *
# import gc

ASCII = False

WIDTH = 50
HEIGHT = 50
side = 15 # Length of a cell's side

def genesis():    
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
                nextCells[x][y] = True
    draw_world(nextCells)
            
def draw_world(grid):
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            if grid[x][y]:
                if ASCII:
                    print('#', end='')
                else:
                    canvas.create_rectangle(x*side, y*side, x*side+side, y*side+side, fill='black')
            else:
                if ASCII:
                    print(' ', end='') # Print the # or space.
                else:                
                    canvas.create_rectangle(x*side, y*side, x*side+side, y*side+side, fill='white', outline="white") # no grid lines
        if ASCII: 
            print() # Print a newline at the end of the row.
                

def live():
    # root.update()
    currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)

    # Calculate the next step's cells based on current step's cells:
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            # Get neighboring coordinates:
            # `% WIDTH` ensures leftCoord is always between 0 and WIDTH - 1
            leftCoord  = (x - 1) % WIDTH
            rightCoord = (x + 1) % WIDTH
            aboveCoord = (y - 1) % HEIGHT
            belowCoord = (y + 1) % HEIGHT

            # Count number of living neighbors:
            numNeighbors = 0
            if currentCells[leftCoord][aboveCoord]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Top-left neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[x][aboveCoord]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Top neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[rightCoord][aboveCoord]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Top-right neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[leftCoord][y]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Left neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[rightCoord][y]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Right neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[leftCoord][belowCoord]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Bottom-left neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[x][belowCoord]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Bottom neighbor is alive.
            if currentCells[rightCoord][belowCoord]:
                numNeighbors += 1 # Bottom-right neighbor is alive.

            # Set cell based on Conway's Game of Life rules:
            if currentCells[x][y] and (numNeighbors == 2 or numNeighbors == 3):
                # Living cells with 2 or 3 neighbors stay alive:
                nextCells[x][y] = True
            elif not currentCells[x][y] and numNeighbors == 3:
                # Dead cells with 3 neighbors become alive:
                nextCells[x][y] = True
            else:
                # Everything else dies or stays dead:
                nextCells[x][y] = False
    draw_world(nextCells)
    # del currentCells
    if ASCII:
        time.sleep(1) # 1-second pause between frames
    # gc.collect()
    root.after(1000, live)
                
    
root = Tk()
root.title("Conway Game of Life")

frame = Frame(root, width=WIDTH*side, height=HEIGHT*side)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='white', width=WIDTH*side, height=HEIGHT*side)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
nextCells = [[False] * WIDTH for i in range(HEIGHT)]
    
genesis()
live()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should have updated your question with a [mre], because it sounds like you making more mistakes than just recreating new objects. The Infinite loop and updating your application should be done with `tkinter.mainloop`

Comment: I've added my code to show you what I had been doing. I used the ASCII flag to prove to myself that the create_rectangle() calls were slowing down the program.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the color of a rectangle object without creating a new rectangle?

Yes. The method is called `itemconfigure`. You need either the rectangle id, or the name of a tag that is associated with the rectangle.

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
...
canvas.itemconfigure(rectangle, fill="red")
```

Comment: Thank you! This greatly speeds up my Tkinter version of the game of life.